# How to view stars rating for my App in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

I want to view the stars vote by users for my app in Google play. Any solution for it?

Comment: Search for you app in Google play ? lol

Comment: are you looking for and API to to see it on the Google play web site?

Comment: yes, I need an API to read it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no API currently for the developer statistics. Apps like [Andlyitics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject&hl=en) use screen scraping and that is why they have to be updated when ever the console changes.

Following from there play store page:

> Please notice that Google doesn't provide a stable API to get download
>   and rating stats. Therefore Andlytics might not work properly if
>   something changes in the Android Market. In that case please be
>   patient while we try to catch up with the changes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by parsing the data from inline JSON located in the HTML. An example approach of scraping app reviews count and rating in Python using `beautifulsoup`, `lxml`, `requests` libraries, and a regular expression.

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Play-Store-App-info-and-reviews#main.py):

```py
# Super-Mario game is being scraped in this example:
# https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.zara&gl=US

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, re, json

params = {
    "id": "com.nintendo.zara", # app name
    "hl": "en",                # language
    "gl": "us"                 # country
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"
}

html = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

# [12] index <script> position is not changing. Other <script> tags position are changing.
# [12] index is a basic app information.
# https://regex101.com/r/DrK0ih/1
basic_app_info = json.loads(re.findall(r"<script nonce=\".*\" type=\"application/ld\+json\">(.*?)</script>", str(soup.select("script")[12]), re.DOTALL)[0])

app_rating = round(float(basic_app_info["aggregateRating"]["ratingValue"]), 1)  # 4.287856 -> 4.3
app_reviews = basic_app_info["aggregateRating"]["ratingCount"]
print(app_rating, app_reviews, sep="\n")

# 4.0
# 1619960
```

---

Create search params as a dictionary:

```py
# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "id": "com.nintendo.zara", # app name
    "hl": "en",                # language
    "gl": "us"                 # country
}
```

Create headers to act as a "real" user visit so Google won't treat your request as a bot request right away:

```py
# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Make a request, pass `params` and `headers` to the request and create a `BeautifulSoup` object where HTML will be processed and parsed:

```py
html = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
```

- [`lxml` is an XML/HTML parser](https://lxml.de/).

Find `<scprit>` tags, parse the needed data from the `[12]` index `<scprit>` tag where all basic app info is located, and then parse only JSON part via regular expression:

```py
# https://regex101.com/r/DrK0ih/1
basic_app_info = json.loads(re.findall(r"<script nonce=\".*\" type=\"application/ld\+json\">(.*?)</script>", str(soup.select("script")[12]), re.DOTALL)[0])
```

- `json.loads()` will convert JSON string to a Python dictionary.

Parsing data via regular expression from an actual JSON response is safer than scraping via CSS selectors. CSS selectors might be changed, and, in this case, you have to render the page in order to scrape the data which will become slow if using browser automation.

Access the data and print it:

```py
app_rating = round(float(basic_app_info["aggregateRating"]["ratingValue"]), 1)  # 4.287856 -> 4.3
app_reviews = basic_app_info["aggregateRating"]["ratingCount"]
print(app_rating, app_reviews, sep="\n")

# 4.0
# 1619960
```

---

If you want to understand how to scrape more data in Python, you can read the rest on [Scrape Google Play Store App in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-play-store-app-in-python/) blog post of mine.

If you want to use a complete solution, you can use [`google-play-scraper` for Python](https://github.com/JoMingyu/google-play-scraper) or [`google-play-scraper` for JavaScript](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper) which are free, or [Google Play Store API](https://serpapi.com/google-play-api) from SerpAPI which is a paid API with a free plan that handles scraping, bypass blocing, scaling for the user.

Answer (score 0):

go to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=

You will find ratings on right side and bottom of the page. If you want o see user reviews. Click on user reviews tab shown above the Description

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty simple.
Go to Google Play Store :https://play.google.com/store?hl=en

Search for your in the top bar.
If you find your app ,you can see the stars vote.

Hope this helps.